# Fetch call to PHP from remote client no error and no data

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I've a problem with calling from Fetch javascript API from a local client to a remote server with PHP.
There are no errors but any data is returned.
When I make same call to the same server where the client is, it works.

same server:
Client: http://localhost:8888/myclient.html
Server: http://localhost:8888/myphp.php //Mamp
It works and returns the JSON.

Remote:
Client: http://127.0.0.1:5000
Server: http://localhost:8888/myphp.php
No errors!! But returns simply nothing

Client code:

```
  <form target="_self" name="formulario" id="formulario">
    <!-- Estamos usando lista desordenada para los campos de formulario
    Es también habitual hacerlo con los elementos de los menús de navegación
    -->
    <ul>
        <!-- 
            H1 y H2 aquí van dentro de la etqueta UL para que no se solape con los campos,
            ya que este UL está en posición absoluta
         -->
        <h2>Envíanos tus datos</h2>
        <h1>Cubre el formulario</h1>
        <!-- 
            Empiezan los campos de formulario
         -->
        <li>
            <!-- Campo obligatorio tipo texto-->
            <label for="nombre"><span class="required">*</span> Tu nombre</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required>

        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- Campo tipo numérico-->
            <label for="edad">Tu edad</label><br>
            <input type="number" name="edad">

        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- Campo obligatorio tipo Email-->
            <label for="email"><span class="required">*</span> Email</label><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>

        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- Campo tipo Tel (teléfono)-->
            Teléfono <br>(formato xxx yyy zzz):<br>
            <input type="tel" name="tel">
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- inputs tipo Radio-button Llevan el mismo nombre 
                para que se reciba un solo dato. Es un solo campo con dos inputs que
                se marca además como obligatorio
            -->
            <span class="required">*</span> ¿Cómo vendrás al centro?
            <hr>
            <input type="radio" id="vehiculo" name="comoviene" value="vehiculo" required>
            <label for="vehiculo">Tengo vehículo</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="andando" name="comoviene" value="andando">
            <label for="andando">Voy andando</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- inputs tipo checkbox. Cada uno es un campo.
            -->
            ¿ Qué vehículos tienes ?<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="coche" name="tipo" value="coche">
            <label for="coche">Tengo coche</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="moto" name="moto" value="moto">
            <label for="moto">Tengo moto </label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="barco" name="barco" value="barco">
            <label for="barco">Tengo barco</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- Campo tipo select, que crea un menú desplegable con las ociones
            -->
            ¿Qué curso quieres?
            <label for="curso">Elige uno</label>

            <select name="curso" id="curso">
                <option value="">Elige uno...</option>
                <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
                <option value="CSS">CSS</option>
                <!-- Este sería el valor seleccionado por defecto
            -->
                <option value="JS" selected>JAVASCRIPT</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- Botón de enviar.
                Es un input pero no envía valores, 
                aunque tiene un value que es el texto que se ve en el botón,  
                y por defecto (si no se pone) es "submit".
            -->
            <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar">

        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
<script>

    let formul = document.getElementById('formulario');
    let path = "http://localhost:8888/CLASE/CURSO-IFCD0110/hola-background/";
    formul.onsubmit = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        async function envio() {
            const datos = new FormData(e.target);
            let toSend = Object.fromEntries(datos);
            //  console.log(toSend)
            let enviar = await fetch(path + 'form.php',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    /*
                    * We also need to stringify the values, turn the
                    * JavaScript object to a single string that is accepted
                    * as JSON. So we are sending one string that contains
                    * all our values
                    */
                    mode: 'no-cors',
                    body: JSON.stringify(toSend),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    }
                });
            let escribir = await enviar.json();
            document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(escribir)
        }
        envio();
  }
 </script>
```

Server code:

```
    <?php
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
     header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, FETCH, OPTIONS");
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access- 
     Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
     $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

     echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
```

Thanks!

EDIT.
Screenshots network tabs
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the Network tab of DevTools to see what you're sending and what's being returned.

Comment: Add `OPTIONS` to allow methods in your header for the preflight request to happen.

Comment: Sure. That shows me the problem. No "". Simply The network says "No data found..."

Comment: @nice_day added. Issue continues

Comment: What is your `path` variable equal to in the `fetch()` call?

Comment: @LuisGar can you share a screenshot of your network tab?

Comment: One server is liveServer of vscode. The other is localhost of mamp
 http://localhost:8888. So the path is http://localhost. Editing the post

Comment: @nice_dev edited. Images added

Comment: Ok, can you add screenshot of Encabezados tab?

Comment: Edited. Added. Can it be something related to ssl? But no errors....

Comment: This is the full path. http://localhost:8888/CLASE/CURSO-IFCD0110/hola-background/form.php If its sent from same path from file contacto.html it returns the JSON ok

Comment: @LuisGar I still don't see OPTIONS in access control allow methods header. Also, this is not related to SSL.

Comment: Sorry. The screenshot is the ancient. Now it appears, with the same result. GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, FETCH, OPTIONS. Editing again

Comment: Ok why is Content -type text/plain in your request headers?

Comment: I don't know. Added headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    } but it still show text/plain. Can be that the problem even working in same server?

Comment: It's easy to try. If you want i send you the files

Comment: On my phone now, but you can share your snippet links and keep.

Comment: Thanks for your try. Pasted full code of both files

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch: _"Note that mode: "no-cors" only allows a limited set of headers in the request: [...] Content-Type with a value of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain"_

Comment: Why are you setting `no-cors` to begin with? That is for cases where you just need to _send_ the request (without "cooperation" from the remote party, in regard to responding with the correct headers to allow the request), but your JavaScript won't get any access to the response afterwards.

Comment: @LuisGar Remove the `mode` and it would work just fine. I was able to get the response.

Comment: I thought I'made that. But not. That was the problem Thnks!.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the set of "no-coors". Without that, works correctly both local and remote.
The problem was I'd tested without the correct headers in the php file.

So the settings are:

```
      {
                method: 'POST',
                /*
                * We also need to stringify the values, turn the
                * JavaScript object to a single string that is accepted
                * as JSON. So we are sending one string that contains
                * all our values
                */
              //  mode: 'no-cors', No-cors was the problem. Thanks for the comments.
                body: JSON.stringify(toSend),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                }
```